# выводить alert в цикле

Tags: javascript

Технически возможно выводить сообщение (alert) в цикле?

```js
var rabbit = 0;
for (x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
  rabbit++;
  alert(rabbit);
}
```

Понимаю, что не верно, потому что браузер ни чего не отображает.
 А как ещё я могу посчитать кроликов?

Comment: а что неверно? Предоставленный код рабочий

Comment: Рабочий код это когда выводится сообщение, а это код у меня ни чего не вывводит. Я ожидаю увидеть пять окон появляющиеся одно за другим. Вместо этого отображается пустая страница html-я

Comment: А у меня выводит. И это стандартное поведение. Где и как ты пытаешься это запустить?

Comment: перенес код в сниппет, при запуске появляются сообщения и будут появляться пока не будет выставлена галка _предотвратить создание дополнительных диалоговых окон на этой странице_

Comment: первый раз для пробы звпускаю в среде разработке WeBuiding, не работает. Потом запускаю в Firefox-e

Comment: При запуске сниппета у тебя показывается диалоговое окно?

Comment: Это подключаемый файл, не встроенный. Не знаю есть ли разница в моём случае.

Comment: нет , ни чего не выводит

Comment: значит проблема в браузерах где пробуешь, возможно какое-то из дополнений может блокировать вызов alert. Попробуй в других браузерах: chrome, edge и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос

```
var rabbit = 0;
for(x = 0; x <= 5; x++){
rabbit++;
}
alert(rabbit);
```

Или

```
var rabbit = 0;
for(x = 0; x <= 5; x++){
rabbit++;
console.log(rabbit);
}
```

Comment: в чем заключается решение? И что именно решает твой ответ?

Comment: Был поставлен вопрос
"А как ещё я могу посчитать кроликов?" я дал ответ как еще можно

Comment: Верхний вариант, без console.log

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за внимание. Код запустился после переноса в head сайта. В виде подключаемого файла по прежнему не работает.

Comment: а ты уверен, что у тебя подключался именно тот файл? был ли в подключаемом файле еще какой-то код?

Comment: Уверен, другого кода не было. Путь к файлу прописывает редактор, я кликаю на нужный файл а он сам прописывает путь к нему.

Comment: была ли ошибка в консоли при этом?

Comment: Нет, ни каких сообщений о ошибках не было.

Comment: не может быть. либо была ошибка, что файл не найден, либо все должно было работать.